# message does not fit sklearn k-means convergence implementation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

In order to re-use the convergence criterion for k-means as implemented in scikit-learn KMeans for my tensorflow-based k-means implementation I need to understand it, but made this observation which I would love to have explained:

KMeans converges with this message:

> Iteration 45, inertia 6.993125 center shift **2.610457e-03** within
>   tolerance **8.374284e-06**

The implementation in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/_k_means.py (line 442ff, function _kmeans_single_lloyd) is as follows:

```python
center_shift_total = squared_norm(centers_old - centers)
if center_shift_total <= tol:
    if verbose:
        print("Converged at iteration %d: "
              "center shift %e within tolerance %e"
              % (i, center_shift_total, tol))
    break
```

The message should be printed only if the value of *center_shift_total* is **smaller or equal** than the value of *tolerance*. As you can see from the output this is not the case in my run of KMeans (*center_shift_total* is in fact **much** larger than *tol*).

How can this happen (or what am I overlooking)? I noted that the "Converged at iteration" part is missing as well, but the observed message definitely makes no sense to me.

Comment: Can you please tell us the version of sklearn by using: `print(sklearn.__version__)`.
And also, exactly what version of python you're using.

Comment: Sure, sklearn 0.21.3 and python 3.7.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Go to the file: `_k_means_elkan.pyx` line 243 (in 0.23.1). In the master branch it would be line 245.

```
        if verbose:
            print('Iteration %i, inertia %s'
                    % (iteration, np.sum((X_ - centers_[labels]) ** 2 *
                                         sample_weight[:,np.newaxis])))
        center_shift_total = np.sum(center_shift)
        if center_shift_total ** 2 < tol:
            if verbose:
                print("center shift %e within tolerance %e"
                      % (center_shift_total, tol))
            break
```

It seems that it's checking the square of `center_shift_total`. While inside `k_means_.py` it's checking for `center_shift_total` without squaring it.

Comment: Excellent find! By specifying algorithm="full" I do get the expected results now. The square in the elkan method is is a bug IMHO since elkan should provide the same result as "full" just with some computations less due the use of the triangle inequality. I found this related (closed) issue: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9795

Comment: Are you able to formulate a PR (removing the "** 2")?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to be more complicated: I removed "** 2" in a fork of scikit-learn but still get different inertia_ and n_iter_ values for algorithm="full" and algorithm="elkan" respectively.

Comment: @Barden Yeah I took a look at it but I'm not sure how it works exactly, I don't think I'll make a pull request for it.

Comment: Can you reproduce with synthetic data? In that case please open an issue. What do you mean by version 0.23.1, that doesn't exist. Did you mean 0.21.3?

Comment: @AndreasMueller Yes I meant 0.21.3

As for reproducing I think Barden could help, I merely found the place in the code where this happens.

Comment: You can also create an issue without an example, though it's not as ideal.

Comment: I created https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15831 (including example for reproduction)